# Plus width using css object in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I expect to get 142 if $('.list').width equal to 100.

```
$('.modal-dialog').css({
       'width': width($('.list').width() + 42)
});
```

Not sure why above code doesn't work, it doesn't work when I do `$('.list').width() + 42` too..

Comment: Didn't you have another question without the 42? Your question needs more context.

Comment: what is your function `width()`?

Comment: @epascarello I expect to get 142 if $('.list').width equal to 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to wrap it around `width()` as this assumes youre trying to call a function. I would try doing it like this:

```
$('.modal-dialog').css({
    'width': ($('.list').width() + 42)
});
```

Comment: then your`.list` is not producing a width. Please provide your HTML and CSS

Comment: when you try to run this `alert($('.list').width())`, what do you get?

Comment: It's something there, your code doesn't work, u can test it if u don't believe me.

Comment: I found a solution, ($('.list').width()) + 42